# Java parsing with Matcher and Regex

Tags: java, regex

I have a very simple problem but I am new to Java Matcher and I am having a hard time figuring out how to use it for my specific problem.

I have a string which is something like `this <not needed content>src="url"<not needed content>src="url2"<not needed content>`

Where <'not needed content'> are the things I want to ignore in my string. I basically want to extract the URLs from the string.

My code currently looks like this

```
Pattern MY_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\src=\"(.*?)\\\"");
Matcher m = MY_PATTERN.matcher(content);
String s = "something";
while (m.find()) {
   s = m.group(1);
}
```

I apologize for such basic, and possibly duplicate question.

Thank you.

Comment: I could use an HTML parser, but this is not a full HTML page, this is a small part of an RSS feed which I was hoping to parse without anything fancy.

Comment: The beginning of your Pattern `"\\src` means one whitespace followed by `rc`. This will never match `src` as `s` is not whitespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why didn't you try a simplier pattern ? Like this one :

```
Pattern.compile("src=\"(.*?)\"");
```

(Not tested, but should be better)

Comment: wow.... that works perfectly, I can't believe I tried so hard. Ill give you answer as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either of the following regexes:

```
src="([^"]+)
src="(.+?"
```